# $this->getProductCollection() returns only 15 items

Tags: magento-1.7, product, collection

I am using the following code for getting products in the **beforeToHtml()** function of a block, but when I get the products in the template file using **$this->getProductCollection()** it returns only 15 items, while running the query in mysql directly returns 120 items.

**Query:**

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_inventory_in_stock`.`is_in_stock` AS `inventory_in_stock`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `cat_index1`.`position`, SUM(sfoi.qty_ordered) AS `ordered_qty` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_inventory_in_stock` ON (at_inventory_in_stock.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND ((at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=1 AND at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1) OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 0 AND at_inventory_in_stock.manage_stock=0) OR (at_inventory_in_stock.use_config_manage_stock = 1 AND at_inventory_in_stock.is_in_stock=1)) INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='2' INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index1` ON cat_index1.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index1.store_id=1 AND cat_index1.category_id IN (43,42,71,50,44,45,54,46,47,51,48,49,52,55) INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS `sfoi` ON e.sku = sfoi.sku GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` ORDER BY `ordered_qty` DESC
```

**Code:**

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name', 'Phones');
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
$collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

$collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
    ->addStoreFilter()
    ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
    ->setCurPage($currentPage);

if(!is_numeric($price) && $price != "-1"){
    $price = explode(',', mysql_escape_string($price));
    //Mage::log(print_r($price,true), null, 'phonefinder.log');
    if(count($price) == 2){
        $start = $price[0];
        if($start != 0) {
            //Mage::log("Adding gteq expression for start amount of : " . $start, null, 'phonefinder.log');
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gteq' => $start));
        }
        $end = $price[1];
        if($end != '-1') {
            //Mage::log("Adding lteq expression for end amount of : " . $end, null, 'phonefinder.log');
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lteq' => $end));
        }
    }
}
if($sortBy == 1)
    $collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'desc');
else if($sortBy == 0)
    $collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'asc');

if($sortBy == 2){
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_item AS sfoi',
        'e.sku = sfoi.sku',
        'SUM(sfoi.qty_ordered) AS ordered_qty')->group('e.entity_id')->order('ordered_qty DESC');

}

$this->setProductCollection($collection);
echo $collection->getSelect();
//exit;
return parent::_beforeToHtml();
```

Comment: Hey Tariq, can you update or close your question? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's probably due to the `$this->getProductsCount()` having a value of 15. This causes the query to only return 15 records.

Do a `var_dump` on this method to see if it is indeed 15.

Comment: yes it is 15, how to replace it, so all products returns?

Comment: remove `setPageSize` method call form your collection

Comment: I tried it. but another error appears in the template file.

Comment: please update your question with the error